# google-drive-api - Update files with my account Admin

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I am the domain administrator "domain.com", and I want to change the files of all users that meet certain conditions.

```
    final FileList result = service.files (). list ()
                           .setSpaces ("drive")
                           .setCorpora ("domain")
                           .setPageSize (1000)
                           .setQ ("name contains 'hello'")
                           .setFields (
                               "nextPageToken, files (id, name, originalFilename, createdTime, owners (input.text, emailAddress))")
                           .setPageToken (pageToken)
                           .execute ();
```

When reviewing the result, I get the files of different users that contain the conditions.

> {"createdTime": "2019-12-07T19: 58: 44.888Z", "id":
>   "78979879879779799797", "name": "hello_1", "originalFilename":
>   "hello_1", "owners": [{"Shirt ":" Name 1 "," emailAddress ":"
>   name1@domain.com "}]}
>
> {"createdTime": "2019-12-07T19: 58: 44.888Z", "id":
>   "78979879879779799797", "name": "hello_1_name2", "originalFilename":
>   "hello_1_name2", "owners": [{"Shirt ":" Name 2 "," emailAddress ":"
>   name2@domain.com "}]

This is what I am looking for, however, at the time of updating the name, I get the error that I do not have the necessary privileges.

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code": 403,
  "errors": [{
    "domain": "global",
    "message": "The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file.",
    "reason": "insufficientFilePermissions"
  }],
  "message": "The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file."
}
```

Will I have to change the permissions of each file?

Answer (score 0):

- When you make a `list` request with the parameter `.setCorpora ("domain")`, you retrieve files that have been shared domain-wide
- However, bot "can edit" and "view only" files will be included in the response
- If the sharing option is "view only", you cannot edit the files or their names